# Compile query from raw string (without using .text(...)) using Sqlalchemy connection and Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, parameter-expansion

I am using Sqlalchemy 1.3 to connect to a PostgreSQL 9.6 database (through Psycopg).

I have a very, *very* raw Sql string formatted using [Psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) syntax which I can not modify because of some legacy issues:

`statement_str = SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=%(user_id)s`

Notice the `%(user_id)s`

I can happily execute that using a sqlalchemy connection just by doing:

```
connection = sqlalch_engine.connect()
rows = conn.execute(statement_str, user_id=self.user_id)
```

And it works fine. I get my user and all is nice and good.

Now, for debugging purposes I'd like to get the actual query with the `%(user_id)s` argument expanded to the actual value. For instance: If `user_id = "foo"`, then get `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 'foo'`

I've seen tons of examples using [`sqlalchemy.text(...)`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#using-text-fragments-inside-bigger-statements) to produce a statement and then get a compiled version. I have that thanks to other answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617291/how-do-i-get-a-raw-compiled-sql-query-from-a-sqlalchemy-expression) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353653/how-to-get-sqlalchemy-query-object-from-raw-sql-string) been able to produce a decent `str` when I have an SqlAlchemy query.

However, in this particular case, since I'm using a more cursor-specific syntax `%(user_id)` I can't do that. If I try:

`text(statement_str).bindparams(user_id="foo")`

I get:
`This text() construct doesn't define a bound parameter named 'user_id'`

So I guess what I'm looking for would be something like

```
conn.compile(statement_str, user_id=self.user_id)
```

But I haven't been able to get that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I ***think*** I got it.

The combination of SqlAlchemy's [`raw_connection`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#working-with-raw-dbapi-connections) + Psycopg's [`mogrify`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify) seems to be the answer.

```
conn = sqlalch_engine.raw_connection()
try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    s_str = cursor.mogrify(statement_str, {'user_id': self.user_id})
    s_str = s_str.decode("utf-8")  # mogrify returns bytes

    # Some cleanup for niceness:
    s_str = s_str.replace('\n', ' ')
    s_str = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', s_str)
finally:
    conn.close()
```

I hope someone else finds this helpful

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this what you want but here goes.

**Assuming statement_str is actually a string:**

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

statement_str = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=%(user_id)s"
params = {'user_id': 'foo'}

query_text = sa.text(statement_str % params)

# str(query_text) should print "select * from users where user_id=foo"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue with that was that `text(...)` attempts to escape `%(user_id)s` to something like `%%(user_id)`

Comment: oh ok. Happy you got a solution.